# Users in Adobe Experience Manager

Tags: java, adobe, aem, aem-6, user-administration

Does AEM provide a feature to allow disabled users to be enabled again? I have a use case where some of the project members joined back AEM project. Admin disabled their users to prevent login. Now I have to enable them again.

Comment: Please check the read access of `/libs`.

Comment: Are you using OOTB functionality or an external login provider integrated into AEM?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, you can make the account active or inactive.

Please see the below screenshot:

[image]